# Already defined in main.obj

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is the code for my problem and i get 4 errors:

> 1. student.obj : error LNK2005: "struct Node * admitedFirstNode" (?admitedFirstNode@@3PAUNode@@A) already defined in main.obj
> 2. student.obj : error LNK2005: "struct Node * allFirstNode" (?allFirstNode@@3PAUNode@@A) already defined in main.obj
> 3. student.obj : error LNK2005: "struct Node * rejectedFirstNode" (?rejectedFirstNode@@3PAUNode@@A) already defined in main.obj
> 4. pb4_OOP_lab1\Debug\pb4_OOP_lab1.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

```
#include "students.h"                          //main 
int main()                                         
{
for(int i=0;i<NR_STUDENTS;i++)
{
    Student *s1=new Student;
    cout<<"Enter name: ";
    getline(cin,s1->name);
    cout<<"Enter garde: ";
    cin>>s1->grade;
    cin.ignore();
    addStudent(s1);
    delete s1;
}

}
#include "students.h"                           //students.cpp

void AddNodeToList(Node *firstNode, Student *studToAdd)
{
Node *nodeToAdd=new Node;
nodeToAdd->student=studToAdd;
nodeToAdd->next=NULL;

if(firstNode==NULL)
{
    firstNode=nodeToAdd;
}
else
{
    Node *temp;
    temp=firstNode;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp->next=nodeToAdd;
}
}
void addStudent(Student *studentToAdd)
{
AddNodeToList(allFirstNode,studentToAdd);
}

void split()
{
Node *temp=allFirstNode;
while(temp->next != NULL)
{
    Student *currentStud=temp->student;
    if(currentStud->grade < GR)
    {
        AddNodeToList(rejectedFirstNode,currentStud);
    }
    else    
    {
        AddNodeToList(admitedFirstNode,currentStud);
    }
}
}

void print(Node *firstNode)
{

if(firstNode==NULL)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    Node *temp=firstNode;
    Student *current=temp->student;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Student name: "<<current->name<<endl;
        cout<<"Student grade: "<<current->grade<<endl;
    }
}
}

#include <iostream>                       //students.h
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int NR_STUDENTS=5;
const double GR=5.0;

struct Student
{
string name;
double grade;
};

struct Node
{
Student *student;
Node *next;
};

Node *allFirstNode;
Node *admitedFirstNode;
Node *rejectedFirstNode;

void addStudent(Student *studentToAdd);
void split();
void sort();
void print();
```

Comment: For posterity, if the other suggestions don't solve your problem, I have gotten this error before because I accidentally did #include "MyFile.cpp" instead of #include "MyFile.h".  Changing it to .h solved my problem.  Worth checking your most recent changes to see if you did that by accident.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The definition `Node * rejectedFirstNode;` in a header file leads to a multiply defined symbol because all translation units that include that header will generate a symbol for it. Instead, in the header, have

```
//students.h
extern Node * rejectedFirstNode;
```

and move the definition in a **single cpp file**:

```
//students.cpp
Node * rejectedFirstNode;
```

It also seems like you're writing C code. Why is this tagged C++? If you're unaware of all C++ has to offer, read a [good introductory book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring variables in students.h and students.h is included in both main.cpp and student.cpp.

You should avoid declaring variables in headers file.

Try to put following code into students.cpp :

```
Node *allFirstNode;
Node *admitedFirstNode;
Node *rejectedFirstNode;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `admitedFirstNode`, `allFirstNode` and `rejectedFirstNode` defined in the header file. This defines it in every cpp, that includes the "students.h" file.

Split the declaration and definition. Declare them in "students.h":

```
extern Node *allFirstNode;
extern Node *admitedFirstNode;
extern Node *rejectedFirstNode;
```

and in "students.cpp" define the variables:

```
Node *allFirstNode;
Node *admitedFirstNode;
Node *rejectedFirstNode;
```

Comment: The extern definitions are not required since these variables are used in students.cpp only